# Is it possible to restore a Kafka Streams state store after a restart without using changelog topics?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

We have 2 **compacted** topics, each containing terabytes of data, which we want to join using Spring Cloud Stream and Kafka Streams. The (simplified) code looks like this:

```
@Bean
public BiConsumer<KTable<String, LeftEvent>, KTable<String, RightEvent>> processEvents() {
    return ((leftEvents, rightEvents) -> {
      leftEvents.join(rightEvents, this::merge)
        .toStream()
        .foreach(this::process);
    });
}
```

The problem with this approach is that using `KTable`s as input parameters results in the creation of **changelog topics** which essentially **duplicate** the source topics since, as mentioned above, both of these topics are already compacted. To avoid duplicating terabytes of data in Kafka, our first attempt was to use `KStream`s as inputs instead, and to transform them into `KTable`s as follows:

```
stream.toTable(
  Materialized
    .<K, V, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as(stateStoreName)
    .withLoggingDisabled()
);
```

thereby disabling logging and hence dispensing with the changelog topics, which in our context seem useless.

However, the following scenario now no longer works:

1. Generate a `LeftEvent` with key `k1`
2. Restart the application
3. Generate a `RightEvent` with key `k1`

The events are no longer joined, although the join works fine if the application is not restarted in-between (i.e. step 1, then 3).

When the application restarts, we would have expected the state stores to be reconstructed from the souce topics in the absence of changelog topics, but this is apparently not the case. In some occasions, we observed that rocksDB files (located in `/tmp/kafka-streams/...`) were used to retrieve data consumed prior to the restart, however we cannot assume that these files will still be available after a restart since we are working in a containerized environment.

Is there a way to support restarts (and achieve fault tolerance) without having to use changelog topics, which in our case duplicate the input topics? If not, we might have to reconsider our use of Kafka Streams...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to enable optimization of the Kafka Streams: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/optimizing-streams.html#optimization-details (#1 is what you are looking for).

Currently, there are two optimizations that Kafka Streams performs when enabled:

1. The source KTable re-uses the source topic as the changelog topic.
2. When possible, Kafka Streams collapses multiple repartition topics into a single repartition topic.

A key thing to point out, since I have made this mistake myself, is do not forget to send the configuration to both the build() and to the construction of KStreams (optimization, as indicated here from the link provided) is done in the build.

```
// tell Kafka Streams to optimize the topology
config.setProperty(StreamsConfig.TOPOLOGY_OPTIMIZATION, StreamsConfig.OPTIMIZE);

// Since we've configured Streams to use optimizations, the topology is optimized during the build.
// And because optimizations are enabled, the resulting topology will no longer need to perform
// three explicit repartitioning steps, but only one.
final Topology topology = builder.build(config);
final KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, config);
```

Now optimization is enabled for all of the Topology, so if you keep that in mind that the #2 optimization is also performed.